# Using MD5 and preventing from SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

I need to know what is the best way to stop SQL injection in a php website.?
Also i have a problem. When i fire any query which contains the data having ' or ", the query does not execeute its funcioning. Whats the reason for this and whatr could be the possible solution? Also i need to know what is MD5 and how can i use it my code for storing data. Also, is it possible to revert back the MD5 text to original text??

How can i use MD5 hash to store password in php. and how to use them later on as from what i have heard , it is not possible to revert back the MD5.

Comment: I would suggest a Google. With regards to ' & " problem, you should post a sample code that you are using.

Comment: Short answer: Use PDO or MYSQLI to prevent SQLinjections, MD5 is not reversable. You may use the `md5()` function to generate a MD5 hash from a text.

Comment: The best way to avoid SQL injection is by using addslashes function

    $name = addslashes($_POST['name']);
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='$name'";

About the "or" function, I need a piece example of the code to help

You can use md5 by using md5() function

    $password = md5($password);

It is impossible to get the original text back.
You cannot revert it back, but you can use something like this:

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM usr WHERE name='$name' AND password ='".md5($password)."'";